# Meteorjs HTML table filter with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, meteor, html-table, filtering

I would like to filter my HTML Table in Meteor using the MongoDB Database.

I have a Template to Display (each) all my Rides in the HTML table.

I would like to implement a jquery selected filter to filter the table.

```
<template name="rides">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="table_format" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Abfahrtsort</th>
<th>Zielort</th>
<th>Gesucht werden</th>
<th>Datum</th>
<th>Plätze</th>
<th>Kommentar</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
{{#each rides}}
<tr>

<td>{{departure}}</td>
<td>{{destination}}</td>
<td>{{searching}}</td>
<td>{{dateandtime}}</td>
<td>{{seats}}</td>
<td>{{comment}}</td>
<td>{{#if currentUser}}<button class="edit">Bearbeiten</button>{{/if}}</td>

</tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="ddtf.js"> </script>
<script>
jQuery('#table_format').ddTableFilter();
</script>`
```

It doesn't display my Data in the table, neither it shows the filter.

Answer (score 0):

try to use ddTableFilter() in jQuery's document ready method

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery('#table_format').ddTableFilter();

});
```